# Why does my Azure App Service Block Requests from the Kentico Scheduler?

Tags: azure, kentico

I recently installed a Kentico website on an Azure App Service. Kentico has a scheduler service that pings an ASHX file on the same website to kickoff scheduled tasks that need to run. The request is sent from the Kentico application to itself but it leaves the server as a web request and comes back. The scheduler service was setup to request this every 60 seconds. In the Kentico event log there were 403 Forbidden errors every 60 seconds from an IP address we had already created an access rule for in Azure.

For example, the error would state the IP address of the request was 111.3.102.102 but we granted access to that IP in the Networking / Access Restrictions part of the App Service already.

Why is the request blocked?

Comment: When you set up your App Service did you allow it to communicate with other Azure resources?  I believe there is a checkbox during the set up that allows this to happen without any need to set specific outbound addresses.

Comment: @BrendenKehren Our client setup the App Service and they aren't sure. I was hoping there might be a setting for this. Do you know where that setting is and what it's called?

Comment: I believe I have mispoken about the web app. It's the Azure Database that allows you to check a box to communicate with other Azure resources not the web app. Either way, I've not run into this previously with the many other sites we've ran in Azure. Do you have a firewall in front of it that could be causing problems?

Comment: Good point. Yes, this is a development site and our client doesn't want anyone to access it that isn't called out in the access list. All IP addresses are denied access unless they are specifically given access in the App Service access list. In other words, the Azure App Service firewall was denying access. This might not be the case for most other apps that haven't defined any access restrictions, like you're saying. We probably won't run into this issue with the production site because we won't have a "Deny all" rule in the access list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kentico Event Log was showing where the request originated from but the Azure App Service was blocking its own Outbound Public IP Addresses. I had to add access rules to allow all of the Outbound IP addresses.

I found the **Outbound IP addresses** on the **Properties** page of the Azure App Service and added all of them (there were 5) to the **Networking** > **Access Restrictions** page of the Azure App Service.